# При выполнении кода вылезает следующее исключение: System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, строки, парсер, int

```
                     if (operSum[3] == '1')
                    {
                        int indexOperSum = 5;
                        string stringIndex = "";
                        while (TryParseCommand(operSum, out _, out _))
                    {
                            stringIndex += operSum[indexOperSum];
                            indexOperSum++;
                            if (operSum[indexOperSum].ToString() == null) break;
                     }
                     int index = int.Parse(stringIndex); 
                     if (isFirstAdd) firstAdd = index;
                     else SecondAdd = index;
```

**При выполнении кода вылезает следующее исключение:** `System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."` в строке `int index = int.Parse(stringIndex);`

*Примечание: функция TryParseCommand работает нормально, ее лучше не трогать, от греха подальше*

Comment: ха-ха (TryParseCommand работает нормально, ее лучше не трогать, от греха подальше) (я её автор)

Comment: если `TryParseCommand` будет `false` при 1-м срабатывании, то `stringIndex` будет `""` – как следствие, инвалидный парсинг

Comment: Как всегда выручаете :)

Comment: В таких случаях надо первым делом печатать куда-нибудь содержимое переменной, в которой явно лежит что-то не то (`stringIndex` в данном случае) и потом думать, как это не то там оказалось.

Comment: @CrazyElf, "надо первым делом печатать куда-нибудь содержимое переменной", а дебагером не воспользоваться? Даже без точек останова, сразу в тот момент, когда вылетает исключение, среда останавливается в проблемном месте и там глядите в значения, ищите что не так на данный момент

Comment: @Нетерпеливыйигуан Да я как-то по-старинке всё. Дебагер не всегда и везде доступен и достаточно интерактивен. Так то да, дебагер в C# хороший, но уж напечатать то значение обычно вообще проблем нет.